# Grails using native queries,Hibernate addEntity, and a getting a map

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

When I map GORM entities to native query results, I get a list back, but I want a map.

So I want each row to have a team property(Team instance) and several custom properties/columns that are produced by the query.

I map team using

```
lookup.addEntity(t,Team.class);
lookup.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
return lookup.list();
```

The result is a list of lists.I have to do...

```
returnedList.each{
    println it[0].id;//team instance
    println it[1];//custom column
}
```

Less read friendly for the next developer than I'd like. Is there a way to get a map back? **(not counting writing my own list-to-map function, which is what I will do if there is not a built in solution)**

Comment: in hql you can do select new map(u.id, u.name) from User u where u.something=:something  - unsure about  the method you are using

Answer (score 0):

Found [hibernat.transform.Transformers class](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/Transformers.html)

import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers
...

```
lookup.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
```

returns map instead of list.